# Html.ValidationMessage renders on all fields, regardless if they're valid or not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My model is correctly validated. If I take a peak in the validation results during debug, I will see that everything is correct. However, *all* my validation results will show, even if only one is invalid. Again, during debug, only one field is correctly showing up in the validation results, but when my view is rendered all our displayed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Widget widget)
{
      if (widge.Valid) 
      {
      // Save to db
      }

      retun View(widget);
}
```

My view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Widget>" %>
// took out a lot of html here
<form action="Create" method="post">
<input name="Widget.City" value="<%= Model.City == null ? "" : Model.City%>" />
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Widget.City")%>
<input name="Widget.Department" value="<%= Model.Department == null ? "" : Model.Department %>" />
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Widget.Department")%>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Let us say City and Department are set to `NotNull` in my model and I correctly put in a City, but leave Department blank. Again, it will show it is invalid on the controller, with the property Department having a problem, yet in my view I'll get "may not be null" messages for *both* properties. If I have 4 properties and 4 ValidationMessage tags in my view, even if one property is not valid ... all 4 will show. What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I think you want to be using

```
Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
```

Not what you're using currently in your view.

Also...  Since you're using a strongly typed view, you should be checking ModelState.IsValid to determine whether or not you should save your Widget.  That is if you're using data annotations on your view model.

Comment: If I use the strongly typed version ... nothing shows up. I believe this is because Html.ValidationMessageFor only renders the last property, so it turns it into Html.ValidationMessage("City") and I need Html.ValidationMessage("Widget.City") ... but I could be wrong.

Comment: I actually just finished working on a project where I had to do this and it worked for me.  ValidationMessageFor doesn't care how shallow or deep the property is in your view model.  For example, on the project I was working on, I used something like this in my strongly typed view: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MySubObject.MyProperty)

Comment: Are you setting any validation annotations on your view model?

Comment: No the only annotation is on the model,  [NotNull(Message = "City not found")], what would explain it showing for the non-strongly typed and not showing for the strongly typed?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as your input to the `[HttpGet]` action of the view?

Since you're using the format `Widget.Property` the view expects the model to have a Widget property containing the data for the widget.. i.e it is looking for `Model.Widget.Property` but your model only contains `Model.Property`. Based on the code posted here, you're only passing the widget back to the view and it will interpret that as having a NULL `Widget` property, thus triggering all NotNull validation.

A solution here is to assign the Widget post model (what you're accepting in the `[HttpPost]` action) to a Widget property of the of the model you're passing back to the view.

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public Widget Widget { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Widget widget)
{
      if (widge.Valid) 
      {
      // Save to db
      }
      var viewModel = new CreateModel() { Widget = widget };

      retun View( viewModel );
}
```

Hopefully I articulated that correctly.. Its been a long day = )